# Make a new vector according to a given vector in R

Tags: r, function, vector

Imagine I give you a vector like `a = (8 - 2) - (7 - 1)` which can be simplified as `z = (8 - 2 - 7 + 1)`.

Now imagine I give you a vector consisting of nine `0`s, `b = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`.

Can `R` turn `a` to the following vector `desired_output = c(1,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0)`?

## The logic

The numbers in `a` are locations of elements in `b` (ex. `8` in `a` means 8th element in `b`).

The logic is to assign either `1` or `-1` to the elements indicated in `a` based on their sign and assign `0` to all other elements in `b` so to get the `desired_output`.

Comment: Do you really need a tidyverse solution? tidyverse is usually used for operations on *data frames* (or tibbles), rather than vectors ... Can  you give us a [mcve] (i.e. if I enter `a = (8 - 2) - (7 - 1)` into R, it will do the operation and assign the value 0 ((8-2) - (7-1) = 6 - 6 = 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your problem setup — in R terms,  `a = (8 - 2) - (7 - 1)` is an *expression* rather than a *vector* — but here's a start:

```r
b <- rep(0,9)
a <- c(8, -2, -7, 1)
b[abs(a)] <- sign(a)
## [1]  1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this elegant answer. I have a [follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73356471/16762740) to this, in case it interests you.

Answer (score 0):

- We can use `for loop`

```
for(i in a){
    if(i > 0) b[i] <- 1
    else b[abs(i)] <- -1
}
```

- Output

```
[1]  1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0
```

- Data

```
a <-  c(8 ,- 2 ,- 7 ,1)
b <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```